# I have a mongo db collection it has object of objects I want to update all the object inside the lteneighbors which has nbrtype as manual

Tags: mongodb

Collection data:

```json
{
    "globalcellid": "00201-292-0",
    "deviceid": "41733-CI9999-S453474X2203870-01-4G",
    "devicename": "41733-CI9999-S453474X2203870-01-4G",
    "cellname": "cell123",
    "vbbudeviceid": "41733-CI9999-S453474X2203870",
    "celltype": "lte",
    "properties": {
        "cellattributes": {
            "radius": 5
        }
    },
    "pciconfig": {
        "poolname": ""
    },
    "workstate": "none",
    "cellstate": "cell-up",
    "nbrtypeanradminstate": {
        "state": {
            "geo": false,
            "manual": true,
            "uereported": true,
            "x2": true
        },
        "isbidirectional": true
    },
    "neighbors": {
        "nbrecgilist": [
            "00103-0-3",
            "00101-0-1",
            "00102-0-2"
        ],
        "lteneighbors": {
            "00101-0-1": {
                "globalcellid": "00101-0-1",
                "deviceid": "",
                "cellcfg": {
                    "nbrtype": [
                        "manual"
                    ]
                },
                "celltype": "lte",
                "primaryplmn": "",
                "secondaryplmns": [
                    "00000"
                ],
                "pci": 100,
                "eci": "1",
                "tac": 0,
                "qoffsetcell": 0,
                "bandname": 67,
                "bandwidth": 10,
                "bandmode": 2,
                "earfcn": 6300,
                "priority": 0,
                "enable": true,
                "mustinclude": false,
                "blacklist": true,
                "alias": "",
                "nodetype": ""
            },
            "00102-0-2": {
                "globalcellid": "00102-0-2",
                "deviceid": "",
                "cellcfg": {
                    "nbrtype": [
                        "manual"
                    ]
                },
                "celltype": "lte",
                "primaryplmn": "",
                "secondaryplmns": [
                    "00000"
                ],
                "pci": 101,
                "eci": "2",
                "tac": 0,
                "qoffsetcell": 0,
                "bandname": 67,
                "bandwidth": 10,
                "bandmode": 2,
                "earfcn": 6300,
                "priority": 0,
                "enable": true,
                "mustinclude": false,
                "blacklist": true,
                "alias": "",
                "nodetype": ""
            },
            "00103-0-3": {
                "globalcellid": "00103-0-3",
                "deviceid": "",
                "cellcfg": {
                    "nbrtype": [
                        "manual"
                    ]
                },
                "celltype": "lte",
                "primaryplmn": "",
                "secondaryplmns": [
                    "00000"
                ],
                "pci": 102,
                "eci": "3",
                "tac": 0,
                "qoffsetcell": 0,
                "bandname": 67,
                "bandwidth": 10,
                "bandmode": 2,
                "earfcn": 3600,
                "priority": 0,
                "enable": true,
                "mustinclude": false,
                "blacklist": true,
                "alias": "",
                "nodetype": ""
            }
        },
        "gsmneighbors": {},
        "umtsneighbors": {}
    }
}
```

I was tried to convert it in array, update and again object of objects but not able to do so

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?  What is the desired output?

Comment: Expected result is for all the lteneighbors  with nbrtype = manual should update blacklist from true to false

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `"nbrtype"` seems to be an array.  What should happen if there are multiple members of the array?